# custom listitem click does not trigger listview.onclicklistener

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, listitem

My first question here. Please go easy on me.

I have a `ListView` with a `onItemClickListener` implemented.

I also have an android custom listItem consisting in a `RelativeLayout` with 2 overlapping children (LinearLayout).

When I click on the ListItem it does NOT trigger the `ListView.onClickListrener` code. 
This happens only if the custom listItem has 2 overlapping children. If it has only one, everything goes well.

Why does that happen? Thanks a lot in advance, it is driving me crazy.

**custom_list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

...

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

 <Button ...>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In MainActivity.java:**

```
mMainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
{   

...//code reachable only when customListItem has only one child

});
```

**I've found my problem**

The problem was that in the custom listItem View I added a Button - which took the focus from the listItem.

Sorry for the ambiguous question.

Comment: use `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: I did actually. I misswrote above. Thx

Comment: is linearlayout taking focus when you click the list item?

Comment: No it does not.
But also it does not take the focus when I have only one LinearLayout (and in that case it works fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with interactive widgets within your custom list item, you should still be able to correctly trigger your `onItemClick` listener by setting

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

on all your interactive widgets (e.g. buttons, checkboxes). For some reason, that does not seem to work with `ImageButton` though.

If that still does not work, consider adding a listener to one / both of the LinearLayouts when creating the list elements in your adapter.